# casting from uchar* to uint* make unpredictable result

Tags: c, arm

I'm compiling this code with C99 (with some different type definitions like uint32 instead of uint32_t) for an old arm architecture.

```
    uint32 x2 = *((uint32 *) &data[t]);
    uint32 x3;
    memcpy(&x3, &data[t], 4);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", x2, x3, data[t], data[t + 1], data[t + 2], data[t + 3]);
```

(data is uchar* and have length > t + 4)

but surprisingly the output is this:

```
-268435454 2 2 0 0 0
```

what is wrong with this casting?

Comment: Check your format specifiers too -- if `int` is 16-bit then using `%d` to print `uint32` causes undefined behaviour. You should probably write `%lu` and explicitly cast the argument to `(unsigned long)` . (In fact it'd be even better to use standard fixed-width type `uint32_t` specified by C99, instead of customized type uint32)

Comment: Better to use `sizeof(x3)` rather than `4`.

Comment: @M.M Or use `"%"PRIX32` from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart if `uint32_t` were used instead. Who knows what `uint32` is

Comment: @M.M the compiler that I'm using, have uint32 instead of uint32_t.

Comment: @Hassan `uint32_t` is part of C99, you said you were using C99

Comment: You need to used `packed(1)` attribute to access `data`

Comment: @M.M excuse me. updated.

Comment: Possibly relevant and/or interesting offsite explanation: https://medium.com/@iLevex/the-curious-case-of-unaligned-access-on-arm-5dd0ebe24965

Comment: Unaligned access may be or may not be supported depending on the ARM version. IMO, you should include the architecture.

Comment: to be both endian and alignment safe you need to build the 32 bit number 8 bits at a time if you want to do something like this.  independent of underlying architecture.  or start with an aligned size uint32_t for example and then if you want to extract bytes at those addresses then mask and shift them out, not the other way around (larger to smaller has a much higher chance of success then smaller to larger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by the rest of the answers, the problem comes from an [unaligned access](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472e/CJAFDFJF.html). While unaligned access is absolutely supported by x64 or x86, you cannot say that it is fully (un/-)supported by ARM, because it is ARM version dependent.
There are three posibilities:

- before ARMv5 (included). ARM didn't support unaligned access which is what `uint32 x2 = *((uint32 *) &data[t]);` is doing (from `LDR` point of view, three of the four bytes of the 32bit variable are unaligned to 4, and just one is aligned), so the result is undefined (hence an error). Given that, the problem has to be fixed by software (on ARM, [`__packed`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472e/CJAFDFJF.html) for unaligned pointers or structs is useful).
- after ARMv7 (included), they do allow unaligned access*, so the code should be valid, without errors (however, performance is a total different topic, and I am pretty sure it will be slower compared with aligned access to 32bit, but this topic deserves its own entry).
- ARMv6. Usually, ARM has something which makes things funnier, and alignment is not going to be different. Here, they added [a bit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/CDFEJCBH.html) in order to select which way you prefer (ARMv5 or ARMv7).

  Considering *"for an old arm architecture"* comment, your case looks like the first one, but if you include your assembly code and architecture, that would be great for a complete answer.

*some instructions will fail as they cannot support it (i.e. [`STM`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html))

Answer (score 4):

The `x2` line causes undefined behavior. Firstly  `data[t]` might not have 32-bit alignment, and secondly, it's probably a strict aliasing violation to read a 32-bit value from that location.

Just remove that line and use the `x3` version.

Comment: data is uchar * and therefor there is no alignment within it. also if there is any alignment in data, memcpy should fails too. Aliasing violation occurs in case of writing. In this example there is only reading from data, but in 3 different ways.

Comment: @Hassan yes, the fact that there is no alignment in `data` is the problem.  There needs to be alignment for the cast to work.  And `memcpy` does not require any alignment.   And aliasing violation can occur for both reading and writing.

Comment: @Hassan Agree about no Aliasing violation .  Disagree about "memcpy should fails too".  `memcpy()` works fine here.

Comment: @chux are you saying there's no aliasing violation in the original code? (if so, you'd be wrong, unless `data` points to malloc'd space and it earlier had values written into it as `uint32`, which we can't tell from the posted code)

Comment: I see AA in the `printf()` due to x3, but not `x2`.

Answer (score -1):

You have several issues here. Do not use pointer punning, use unions for it.

Your `printf` format is wrong as well. You should use `%u` instead of `%d`.